# jquery - triggering change event on select control - can't determine value afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I have the following jquery code:

```
$("#ruletypes").change(function()  {                        
    var selectedtype = this.value;                  
    var url;
    if (selectedtype == 1) {
        url = url1;
    } else {
        url = url2;
    }                       
    $.getJSON(
        url,
        function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data); //converting to a javascript object vs. just string....                                  
            if (data !=null){
                //remove everything in current list.
                $('#contact_types')
                .find('option')
                .remove() 
                .end()                      
                //loop through results and add each one     
                $.each(data, function(i) {
                    $('#contact_types')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",this.id)                                                  
                    .text(this.description));
                }); //end .each                             
            }//end if
        }//end function(data)
    );//end getJSON.    

    //set default values for contact type
    if (selectedtype == 1)  {                   
        $('#contact_types').val(2).change();  
    } else  {
        $('#contact_types').val(1).change(); 
    }
});//end ruletypes.change

$("#contact_types").change(function () {
    var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").html();
    alert("select value of contact type is" + selectedtext);
    alert(this.value);
});
```

My problem / question is that once I programmtically trigger the change event for the contact_types select box, I can't seem to be able to determine what the value is..
The two alert statements that I have  return undefined and null respectively.

I've also tried .text().

Can you tell me where my bug is?  I need to be able to determne the value of the currently selected item in contact_types.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: Why don't you use your console at first

Comment: adeno, if we were experts at coding, we wouldn't be asking for help. i'll try to fix the syntax errors... but you can spare us the obscene language

Comment: @markli What obscene language ? adeneo points what should be an evidence : the debugging/improving/publishing of any code can only starts after it has been correctly indented. And it's totally independent of the coder experience.

Comment: dystroy, you missed the earlier post.  it's now been removed and the only comment left is the one about indentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should be using `this.value` to get the currently selected value through an `onchange` event. Fixed up the obvious syntax errors (undeclared variable, missing `)}` etc):

```
$("#ruletypes").change(function () {
    var selectedtype = this.value;
    if (selectedtype == 1) {
        $('#contact_types').val(2).change();
    } else {
        $('#contact_types').val(1).change();
    }
});

$("#contact_types").change(function () {
    var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").html();
    alert("select value of contact type is" + selectedtext);
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fgQt3/

Comment: hey thanks. i'll give that a try. i actually do have everything declared...but in my attempt to only give the pertinent code, I forgot to show you the declarations and the closing function stuff.  sorry about that.  my bad.

Comment: tymeJV, I've edited my post to include all code. I've tried your suggestion but for some reason, I'm still getting nulls.

Comment: Hmm...anything in the console?

Comment: Actually, think I got it, you're probably receiving nulls since the AJAX request is ASYNC, it's completing the function before the request.

Comment: ah.. interesting... i'll test that out.

Comment: that was the issue.  the ajax request.  i didn't have the data yet!  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following:

```
$("#contact_types").bind('change', function(e) {
alert(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

or simply use: `alert($(this).val());` inside that change event.

Comment: `live` ? Really ? Please look for it in current documentation.

Comment: @dystroy, You are right, `Live` may causes problem with change event.This is because `live` relies on event bubbling and `change` event does not bubble up. hence I have edited it to `bind` method.